# Memory efficient solution to replace invalid values in a large DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

This question is a continuation of the following:
[How to replace certain rows by shared column values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625099/how-to-replace-certain-rows-by-shared-column-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Let's say I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13], ['Bob', '#'], ['Bob', '#'], ['Bob', '#'], ['Clarke', '#']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'], dtype=float)

     Name Age
0    Alex  10
1     Bob  12
2  Clarke  13
3     Bob   #
4     Bob   #
5     Bob   #
6  Clarke   #
```

Rows 3-6 have invalid values, the string `#`. These should be replaced by valid values, outputting:

```
     Name Age
0    Alex  10
1     Bob  12
2  Clarke  13
3     Bob  12
4     Bob  12
5     Bob  12
6  Clarke  13
```

The pandas solutions discussed to replace these values discussed were using `coerce`, or replacing with a subset data frame:

```
v = df.assign(Age=pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce')).dropna()
df['Age'] = df['Name'].map(v.set_index('Name').Age)
```

or

```
d= df[df['Age']!='#'].set_index('Name')['Age']
df['Age']=df['Name'].replace(d)
```

The problem is for a pandas DataFrame with millions of rows, these pandas-based solutions become very memory intensive.

In situations like these with pandas, what would be the most practical solution?

I could try to create a massive dictionary using `df[df['Age']!='#']`, with `Name: Age` as the key-value pairs. Then, iterate through the original pandas DataFrame row by row; if there is a row with Age==`#`, then replace it based on the key-value pair in the dictionary. The downside to this is, a for-loop will take forever.

Are there other solutions which would have better performance?

Comment: after `d= df[df['Age']!='#'].set_index('Name')['Age']`, how much memory is `d` consuming, as compared to `df`?

Comment: Can you please let me know if you've tried this and are still facing issues?

Comment: @pnv Let me check

Comment: @coldspeed I'll be sure to update you soon! Apologies for the delay; I will be back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try something a bit more memory efficient, like dictionary-based replacement instead of series-based?

```
mapping = dict(df.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='first').values)
df['Age'] = df['Name'].map(mapping)

print(df)
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
3     Bob   12
4     Bob   12
5     Bob   12
6  Clarke   13
```

Another alternative would be using a list comprehension:

```
mapping = dict(df.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='first').values)
df['Age'] = [mapping.get(x, np.nan) for x in df['Name']]

print(df)
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
3     Bob   12
4     Bob   12
5     Bob   12
6  Clarke   13
```

This should work assuming valid values in "Age" come first.

Comment: @jezrael yes, I get it... I'm trying to microoptimze here. There are more moving parts in my initial answer (in the other post), because performance wasn't made a concern by OP.

Comment: ya, so is possible some way measure it? like [`memory_usage`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html) ?